# Get Date Products last updated in Opencart 3

Tags: date, opencart, product

I am trying to get the latest date from Opencart 3 Products field 'Date_available' and post it into the very top of the header page. I am currently doing it by manually adding the date in the settings/store page where I have placed a text box linked to the database variable - I use the code in cotroller Settings.php:

```
if (isset($this->request->post['config_updated'])) {
        $data['config_updated'] = $this->request->post['config_updated'];
    } else {
        $data['config_updated'] = $this->config->get('config_updated');
    }
```

and the code in sttings twig:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-updated">{{ entry_updated }}</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="config_updated" value="{{ config_updated}}" placeholder="{{ entry_updated}}" id="input-updated" class="form-updated" />
            </div>
          </div>
```

Here I can enter the date and it shows as image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1HTE.png) Products last updated: 25/05/2020 : 21:12:32

How can I find the latest date in oc_products_date_available and show it in the place described above? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here are all the steps.

First of all, backup your files.

Then,
go to folder:

```
catalog/model/catalog
```

Inside the folder common create a new file called

```
headerdate.php
```

Inside the headerdate.php add the following code:

```
    <?php
class ModelCatalogHeaderdate extends Model {
    public function getLastDate() {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT date_available FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "product` ORDER BY `date_available` DESC LIMIT 1");
        return $query->row['date_available'];
    }

}
```

Save the changes.

Now open file:

```
catalog/controller/common/header.php
```

and before the line:

```
return $this->load->view('common/header', $data);
```

add the following code:

```
$this->load->model('catalog/headerdate');
$data['last_product_update'] = $this->model_catalog_headerdate->getLastDate();
```

Save settings and you've completed the hard part.

Now, the last and easiest part, is that you open your theme's header.twig file and you can show your date by using the variable we've set above like this:

```
{{ last_product_update }}
```

Don't forget to save your changes and upload them to your eshop.